# Type-safe IDs in service layer for error prevention

Tags: identity, dto, service-layer, type-safety

I'm currently writing on the business logic of an Java-application. I've splitted it into domain layer and service layer. The service layer provides interfaces which allow access on the data via data transfer objects.

The idea i've got is to make "typesafe" IDs. That could be simple described as that the method `getId()` doesn't return a long but instead an object of an special class which consists of the ID value and also a Class-field to determine the type which object is referred. The motivation befind this is, that I used the ID of the wrong type which lead to a difficult-to-detect error.

The ID-Class would look something like this:

```
public class ObjectId<T>
{
    private Class<T> type;
    prviate long id;
    ...
}
```

The class is then used in a DTO:

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    public ObjectId<SomeDTO> getId(){...}
    ...
}
```

and also in the service:

```
public interface TheService
{
    public SomeDTO getSome(ObjectId<SomeDTO> id);
    ...
}
```

I might be completly wrong, but beside some drawbacks like a more complex model it also offers the possibility to prevent such errors at the outsets.

Is it a good or a crazy idea?

Comment: Why would you use a class and not just a GUID?

Comment: I use a numeric ID and also the type to which instance the ID referes to. With class I meant the type. How did you understand it?

Comment: I thought you meant it as in object oriented class

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin I use Java, the type of the field is java.lang.Class. Did you meant that?

Comment: I see the id is always of type long. Could not understand the added advantage of storing the class type. What is the use of that, What was the problem without that.

Comment: @Tech-user So the ID from getID() can't be used for an object of an other type. It also provides a type-indepentant ID. Without it somebody could call A.getID() and use the result in Service.getB(), which is not correct.
But in the case of identity you are right. In the domain model I'm just using a long for the ID.

Comment: I am not sure StackOverflow is the correct place to discuss this as the question is subjective, it belongs better at Programmers or CodeReview. In any case though, I did implement something similar where I work in C++. You will also want to make your class comparable and hashable so it can be used as a key.